# GRASS ERROR "raster not found" with i.image.mosaic tool in QGIS 3.10.10

Tags: qgis-3, grass-gis, mosaic, image-mosaic

I'm trying to mosaic multiple DEM files using the GRASS 7 'i.image.mosaic' function in QGIS 3.10.10, on a Mac. I keep getting the same error code and have not been able to figure it out.

Details of error code below...

```
i.image.mosaic log:

QGIS version: 3.10.10-A Coruña
QGIS code revision: 1869829378
Qt version: 5.12.3
GDAL version: 2.4.1
GEOS version: 3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.2 b55d2125
PROJ version: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'i.image.mosaic' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '', 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '', 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'input' : ['/Users/Victoria/GIS_Data/ARP/DEM/092f09_e.dem','/Users/Victoria/GIS_Data/ARP/DEM/092f16_e.dem'], 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs"
r.external input="/Users/Victoria/GIS_Data/ARP/DEM/092f09_e.dem" band=1 output="rast_5fd57c27bbe5219" --overwrite -o
r.external input="/Users/Victoria/GIS_Data/ARP/DEM/092f16_e.dem" band=1 output="rast_5fd57c27be35f20" --overwrite -o
g.region n=50.00010416666667 s=49.49989583333333 e=-123.99989583333334 w=-124.25010416666667 res=0.00020833333333333318
i.image.mosaic input=rast_5fd57c27bbe5219,rast_5fd57c27be35f20 output=outputfff97a59a13347538da5fe8dec81f73d --overwrite
g.region raster=outputfff97a59a13347538da5fe8dec81f73d
r.out.gdal -t -m input="outputfff97a59a13347538da5fe8dec81f73d" output="/var/folders/z8/wfb7q_xs5hd3pzgngdbcg_p00000gn/T/processing_79d44a19e1014c7d9a4313d065933bc9/d3c09a560d054515abe933f818cf6c81/output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
Executing </var/folders/z8/wfb7q_xs5hd3pzgngdbcg_p00000gn/T/processing_79d44a19e1014c7d9a4313d065933bc9/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> ...
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
Over-riding projection check
Reading band 1 of 1...
Link to raster map <rast_5fd57c27bbe5219> created.
Over-riding projection check
Reading band 1 of 1...
Link to raster map <rast_5fd57c27be35f20> created.
ImportError: No module named site

ERROR: Raster map <outputfff97a59a13347538da5fe8dec81f73d> not found
ERROR: Raster map or group <outputfff97a59a13347538da5fe8dec81f73d> not found
Execution of </var/folders/z8/wfb7q_xs5hd3pzgngdbcg_p00000gn/T/processing_79d44a19e1014c7d9a4313d065933bc9/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> finished.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/bin/_grass76", line 2207, in <module>
main()
File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/bin/_grass76", line 2155, in main
clean_all()
File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/bin/_grass76", line 1789, in clean_all
gsetup.clean_default_db()
File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/etc/python/grass/script/setup.py", line 220, in clean_default_db
conn = gdb.db_connection()
File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/etc/python/grass/script/db.py", line 108, in db_connection
nuldev = file(os.devnull, 'w')
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/grass76.sh: line 20: /var/folders/z8/wfb7q_xs5hd3pzgngdbcg_p00000gn/T/processing_79d44a19e1014c7d9a4313d065933bc9/grassdata/temp_location/PERMANENT: is a directory
Starting GRASS GIS...
Executing </var/folders/z8/wfb7q_xs5hd3pzgngdbcg_p00000gn/T/processing_79d44a19e1014c7d9a4313d065933bc9/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> ...

ERROR: Raster map <outputfff97a59a13347538da5fe8dec81f73d> not found
ERROR: Raster map or group <outputfff97a59a13347538da5fe8dec81f73d> not found
Execution of </var/folders/z8/wfb7q_xs5hd3pzgngdbcg_p00000gn/T/processing_79d44a19e1014c7d9a4313d065933bc9/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> finished.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/bin/_grass76", line 2207, in <module>
main()
File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/bin/_grass76", line 2155, in main
clean_all()
File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/bin/_grass76", line 1789, in clean_all
gsetup.clean_default_db()
File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/etc/python/grass/script/setup.py", line 220, in clean_default_db
conn = gdb.db_connection()
File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/etc/python/grass/script/db.py", line 108, in db_connection
nuldev = file(os.devnull, 'w')
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/grass76.sh: line 20: /var/folders/z8/wfb7q_xs5hd3pzgngdbcg_p00000gn/T/processing_79d44a19e1014c7d9a4313d065933bc9/grassdata/temp_location/PERMANENT: is a directory
Execution completed in 9.14 seconds
Results:
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>/var/folders/z8/wfb7q_xs5hd3pzgngdbcg_p00000gn/T/processing_79d44a19e1014c7d9a4313d065933bc9/d3c09a560d054515abe933f818cf6c81/output.tif</li></ul>
```

GRASS message log:

```
2020-12-12T21:27:51
 INFO
 processInputs end. Commands: ['g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs"', 'r.external input="/Users/Victoria/GIS_Data/ARP/DEM/092f09_e.dem" band=1 output="rast_5fd57c27bbe5219" --overwrite -o', 'r.external input="/Users/Victoria/GIS_Data/ARP/DEM/092f16_e.dem" band=1 output="rast_5fd57c27be35f20" --overwrite -o', 'g.region n=50.00010416666667 s=49.49989583333333 e=-123.99989583333334 w=-124.25010416666667 res=0.00020833333333333318']

2020-12-12T21:27:51
 INFO
  processCommands end. Commands: ['g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs"', 'r.external input="/Users/Victoria/GIS_Data/ARP/DEM/092f09_e.dem" band=1 output="rast_5fd57c27bbe5219" --overwrite -o', 'r.external input="/Users/Victoria/GIS_Data/ARP/DEM/092f16_e.dem" band=1 output="rast_5fd57c27be35f20" --overwrite -o', 'g.region n=50.00010416666667 s=49.49989583333333 e=-123.99989583333334 w=-124.25010416666667 res=0.00020833333333333318', 'i.image.mosaic input=rast_5fd57c27bbe5219,rast_5fd57c27be35f20 output=outputfff97a59a13347538da5fe8dec81f73d --overwrite']
```

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures so that they are available to searches and can be easily read on all devices.

Comment: Similar problem here (in my case, the not-found raster file is the g.region raster=outputb0d5979d951f408f8e0b971c6a68fdf7). Wondering whether it can be related to a defective installation.